# GitHub personal access token gets destroyed even after putting and using it in project secrets

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions, flutter-web

I've a personal access token that I'd need for my app to run. So I encoded the file using base64 by this `base64 dotenv`, added the output to my project secrets, and removed the `dotenv` from version control.

In order to build my project successfully, I would need this file back. So, in my GitHub actions, I'm putting this file back just before the build by decoding using project secret:

```
- run: echo $SECRET_KEY | base64 -d > dotenv
  env:
    SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
```

But as soon as my GitHub Action finishes the job, my personal access token gets destroyed by GitHub. This is the entry in the GitHub security log:

```
GitHub System – oauth_authorization.destroy
Removed authorization for personal access token (flutterDevFolio)
```

I found no other options to use project secrets in flutter web.

Comment: This is obvious. You shouldn't push the build files with the secrets. What you're doing is actually creating a file with the secret and starting the build. The ultimate end files will be containing the secret somewhere anyway, which isn't safe.